# Is there any term used for multiple hat tricks?

Tags: cricket, terminology

If a bowler takes more than three sequential wickets (say six wickets) in one over, would this be called as two hat-tricks or does this feat, however unlikely, has a different name?

Comment: It isn't remotely official or widespread, but one of my relatives came up with the term _qua-trick_ to refer to 4 wickets in 4 balls. After doing some Google searching, it appears that the term is occasionally used in football.

Comment: @Spinner, interesting. Never heard that, but it makes sense, and does appear quite after on the web :-)

Answer (score 4):

Six wickets in six balls would in fact be 4 hat tricks.

```
1) Balls 1, 2 & 3, 
2) Balls 2,3 & 4, 
3) Balls 3,4 & 5 and 
4) Balls 4, 5 & 6.
```

There is no term used other than "hat trick" for 3 consecutive wickets.

Comment: Wrong! If you take 6 wickets in 6 balls it doesn't count as 4 hat-tricks but it is count as two different hat-trick. Have a look at [this list of ODI Hat-tricks](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/263626.html). Here SL Malinga's hat-trick is counted only one even he took 4 wickets in 4 balls.

Comment: @hims056 no you are wrong. Theres a reason why there is an asterisk. Every commentator I have ever hear commentate a hattrick then proceeds to say 'Can they get the double hattrick?'.

Comment: @user1672694 - Have you read the links I have provided?

Comment: @hims056 read my comment again

Comment: @user1672694 - I really don't understand what do you want to say.

Comment: @user1672694 [Downvoting](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) is an acceptable way to address "an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect," and [commenting](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) is an acceptable way to provide "constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post."

Comment: Generally you do not count each goal/wicket more than once for hat tricks. For example, most people do not consider 4 goals/wickets to be "2 hat tricks" (or a "double hat trick").

Comment: @edmastermind29 let me know when downvoting comments is possible then

Comment: @user1672694 Comments are not downvoted. The privilege to downvote questions/answers are "Awarded At: 125 Reputation." You are on your way.

Comment: @edmastermind29 I was simply pointing out the invalidity of your comment. I know comments can't be downvoted, making your comment pointless

Comment: @user1672694 You got me there. Nonetheless, the main purpose of my comment toward you is to keep the criticism constructive and not derisive, and ways to do that *in general* are through downvoting and commenting. "Invalid" or "pointless" or not, the purpose remains applicable.

Answer (score 2):

[Definition of Hat-Trick by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat-trick)

> a bowler taking a wicket off each of **three consecutive deliveries** that he bowls in a single match (whether in the same over or split up in two consecutive overs, or two overs in two different spells, or even spread across two innings of a test match or first-class cricket game).

So a single hat-trick means taking a wicket off each of three consecutive deliveries. So if a bowler takes six wickets in six consecutive deliveries, it will be considered as two [different] hat-tricks. There is no special name for this since no one has achieved this feat but we may say it **double hat-trick**. However if a bowler takes four wickets in four consecutive deliveries it is called as **four in four** but the term **double hat-trick** has also been used in the media*. So there is no special term for that. Everyone refer them in their own term.

<sub>* taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat-trick#Cricket)</sub>

Comment: I am fairly sure that "double-hat trick" is conventionally used for 4 wickets in 4 balls. Note that Wikipedia _itself_ (in the bottom of the subsection linked by you; so it is not just the media) refers to five wickets in five balls as a triple hat-trick. But I think that any hat-trick, be it of the normal (3), double (4) or triple (5) variety, still counts as _one_ hat-trick. I am unsure about the quadruple (6) hat-trick, through. (Whether that would count as one trick or two tricks.) :)

Answer (score 1):

[A 'perfect over' of 6 wickets taken with 6 consecutive balls](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/sport/news/article.cfm?c_id=4&objectid=11789075)<sup>[bbc](http://www.bbc.com/sport/cricket/38743940)</sup> was achieved by Australian Aled Carey on 21 January 2017 while bowling for his club Golden Point against East Ballarat. This perfect over consisted of 2 catches, an LBW and 3 bowled.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat-trick#Cricket) and [his club Golden Point tweet](https://twitter.com/GoldenPointCC/status/822719319079456768/photo/1) states this as **quadruple Hat-Trick**, while few media like [deccanchronicle](https://www.deccanchronicle.com/sports/cricket/260117/stunning-aussie-club-cricketer-aled-carey-scalps-2-hat-tricks-in-an-over.html), [thenews](https://www.thenews.com.pk/latest/182107-6-balls-6-wickets-and-2-hat-tricks-an-Aussie-bowlers-perfect-over) and [article.wn](https://article.wn.com/view/2017/01/26/Stunning_Aussie_club_cricketer_Aled_Carey_scalps_2_hattricks/) states this as **2 hat-tricks in an over** and some other media like [zeenews](http://zeenews.india.com/cricket/six-deliveries-six-wickets-australian-club-cricketer-aled-carey-bowls-the-perfect-over_1971007.html), [scroll](https://scroll.in/field/827728/australian-club-cricketer-bowls-the-perfect-over-six-wickets-in-six-balls) and [financialexpress](http://www.financialexpress.com/sports/australian-bowler-stuns-opposition-picks-6-wickets-in-six-balls/525139/) states this as **double hat-trick**.

So, as hims056 said in his answer, there is no special term for that. Everyone refer to these hat-tricks in their own term.

Answer (score -4):

4 wickets in 4 balls may be called qadri-trick; 5 wickets in 5 balls penta-trick ; Then there is change in the over.Yet, for 6 successes in 6 consecutive events may be called hexa-trick; 7 in 7 hepta-trick; 8 in 8 octa-trick; 9 in 9 nona-trick; 10 in 10 deca-trick; 11 in 11 undeca-trick and 12 in 12 dodeca-trick! How's that!

Comment: Do you have a reference for where any of these terms have been used?

Answer (score -4):

A bowler taking six consecutive wickets in a over means two hatricks not a term like double hatrick.

Comment: Do you have any references which you can use to support this answer? At the moment, this sounds like it is simply your opinion, which is not the sort of answer we look for on Stack Exchange.