# Which word is used for 4 wickets in 4 balls? Question about 4 in 4 not multiple hat-trick

Tags: cricket, terminology

Which word is used when bowler takes 4 continuous wickets in 4 balls? (such as hat-rick for 3 wickets in 3 balls)

Comment: My question for 4 wicket in 4 balls not multiple hat-trick.

Comment: That may be the case, but the linked question still provides an answer to your query.

Comment: Did you read [the whole answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/3305/540) there?

Comment: Yeah I read the whole answer and I was satisfied with that answer

Answer (score 1):

It is **Four in Four** according to **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat-trick)**.

> Taking two wickets in two consecutive deliveries is occasionally known
>   as a brace, or (more commonly, especially until the next delivery has
>   been made) being on a hat-trick. Four wickets in four balls is
>   referred to in cricket literature and record books as four in four but
>   the term double hat-trick has also been used in the media, as it will
>   contain two different, overlapping sets of three consecutively
>   dismissed batsmen.

**Note :** Cricket does not define an official term for 4-in-4.